# how to declare a php variable in POST scope

Tags: php, variables

I have this code and it works.

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='liga' value='Liga'>";
if (isset($_POST['liga'])) {
    unset($_POST['liga']);
    liga();
?>
```

But I need change the name LIGA to the php variable $on. I tried this but don't work.How can I insert the variable in this code?

```
$on=1;
 echo "<input type='submit' name='$on' value='Liga'>";

if (isset($_POST['$on'])) {
    unset($_POST['$on']);
    liga();
}
?>
```

Comment: And why do you need to do this?!

Comment: I will create multiploe variables

Comment: You should read somethink about data types ;)  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that variables inside single quotes don't get interpolated whereas variables inside double quotes do.

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='$on' value='Liga'>";
```

becomes

```
<input type='submit' name='1' value='Liga'>
```

But `$_POST['$on']` stays the same. To solve this, use `$_POST[$on]` (or the equivalent `$_POST["$on"]`).

Comment: Your are right with the quotes, but if $on = 1, it won't work anyway because 1 is a numerical index.

Comment: @MarioA Good point, but why shouldn't it work? Don't numbers work as names?

Comment: ok but I need echo the imput because it is inside php code, and I need create multiple buttons dynamically

Comment: @RobertoBahia I don't understand your comment. Is this not answering your question?